# How to order this data - for...loop leads to error

Tags: r

I'm having trouble trying to iterate through data and combine my columns:

```
names <- c()
haplotypervalue <- c()

x <- as.numeric(nrow(noNAhaplotypes)) - 1

for (i in 1:x) {
  if (haplotypevalue[i] %in% haplotypevalue && i > 2) {
    j <- i + 1
    haplotypevalue[[i]] <-  c(haplotypevalue, noNAhaplotypes$value[j])
    next
  }
  
  names <- c(names, noNAhaplotypes$name[i])
  haplotypevalue <- c(haplotypevalue, noNAhaplotypes$value[i])
}
```

My data looks something like this:
[image]

What I am trying to do is effectively loop through the data frame (noNAhaplotypes), and check to see if the 'name' at each row already exists in the name vector I have created. If it does, I want to add corresponding value from the value column to the haplotypevalue vector.

My results should be something like:
name: [A, B, C, D...]
haplotypevalue: [12345, 34565, 34568, {12346, 34568, 23458.5}...]

This means haplotypevalue[4] should yield all the 3 values associated with 'D'.

I've been trying to do a for loop but I get:
"
Error in haplotypevalue[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

> 

"

Apologies if the data or variable names are confusing or if some spellings don't match up. I changed the names to protect data integrity.

Comment: change the very beginning to `haplotypervalue <- list()` ie use list instead of vector

Comment: `split(df$value, df$name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
haplotypervalue <- split(df$value, df$name)

$A
[1] 12345

$B
[1] 34565

$C
[1] 34568

$D
[1] 12346.0 34568.0 23458.5

$E
[1] 21237.2 19015.9 16794.6

$F
[1] 14573.3

$G
[1] 12352

$H
[1] 10130.7
```